# I need to delete rows in pandas that satisfy the condition

Tags: python, dataset, data-science

I have a pandas data set, and I need to delete all lines.

All lines that have a specific row in the 'genre' column.

The problem is that all the values in this column are a string from the list of genres.

[image]

This line works, but only deletes the lines where 'Hentai' is the only value.

[image]

Comment: You should provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "in" operator to check if "hentai" is in "genre".

```
for x in range(0,len(df)):
    if 'Hentai' in df.iloc[x,2]:
        df = df.drop([x],axis=0)
```

Comment: I already tried, but it produced a ton of KeyErrors

Comment: Could you check my comment? I provided the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't answer, I find the solution:

```
f = df[~df.genre.str.contains("Hentai", na=False)]
```

The `na` argument is needed to skip empty values, because otherwise, Python may throw an error :

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: @ Unico_rn-de if you wish that people don't answer any more then please press the accept (tick) button. That will let users know that you have found you answer and aren't looking anymore